# How to change the size of line AutoCompleteTextView?

Tags: android, xml

Does anybody know How to change the size of line an AutoCompleteTextView?
I need the black line to be more long in edges.
This is my Xml code:

```
    <AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/autoComplete_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:hint="                   Where you want to Go?"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColorHint="#0b0b0b"
    android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
    android:dropDownHeight="25dp"
    />
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autocomplete_country);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter  = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item, R.id.item, COUNTRIES);
    textView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: thank you! it work to me now.

Answer (score 2):

remove margin then it will occupy all the width

or try to reduce

```
android:layout_margin="16dp"
```

Comment: Thank you!! it work to me now :)